# Font issue on Ubuntu machine in parsing PDF File

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04, text-mining, apache-tika

I have an application on my Ubuntu 14.04.x Machine. This application does text mining on PDF files. I suspect that it is using Apache Tika etc...

The problem is that, during its reading process, I get the following warning:

```
2015-09-10 14:15:35 [WARN] FontManager Font not found: CourierNewPSMT
2015-09-10 14:15:36 [WARN] FontManager Font not found: CourierNewPSMT
2015-09-10 14:19:33 [WARN] FontManager Font not found: Helvetica
2015-09-10 14:19:34 [WARN] FontManager Font not found: ESQWSF+Helvetica
2015-09-10 14:19:34 [WARN] FontManager Font not found: ESQWSF+Helvetica
2015-09-10 14:19:34 [WARN] FontManager Font not found: ESQWSF+Helvetica
......
```

How can I get those fonts on my machine? Or is it some java lib that I am missing for fonts?

Comment: Did you check your FontManager.java on your linux machine?

Comment: What should i check about it ?

Comment: Are you able to change the code? Is it your application or are you just running this application?

Comment: This fonts are part of Microsoft core fonts, have you installed `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` deb package?

Comment: Yes I have it installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do a three step approach to fix this issue.

1. Analyse what files are searched for and not found using strace
2. Use apt-file to search for the package providing these files
3. Install the missing package

1.) Install strace if it's not already installed `sudo apt-get install strace`

Check what files are used by your app:

`$> strace <your app> 2>&1 | grep open`

you can further filter this for ENOENT errors:

`$> strace <your app> 2>&1 | grep open | grep ENOENT`

Now you should know what files are missing.

2.) Check what package is providing this file.
(dpkg -S  only works for already installed packages)

```
su
apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
apt-file search <filename>
```

3.) install that package using `apt-get install <package>`

I've no Ubuntu here, but the MS fonts are normally available in a package called "mscorefont" or similar.